# IE8 Developer Tools not able to select?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

I've grown very fond of the Devloper Tool in IE8 (pressing F12) but for some reason, it is no longer functioning, pressing F12 only results in the selection tool opening, but no interaction with the page I opened the tool in is happening, usually a blue border is surrounding your "selected" element on the page, this functionality is however not working anymoew, I have two colleagues, one where he has the same problem, and another where his developer tool still works as expected.

I'm wondering if this has happened to anyone else, and if they have an idea on what could cause this? - a solution would be cool aswell ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my colleague thought out of the box, the Developer Tool, did not get proper focus. right clicking the application in the taskbar, selecting move gave it focus, and the application size where shrinked to a minimum, expanding it made the Developer Tool work as expected :)

Answering in case anyone runs into the same "problem" :)

Answer (score 5):

Just for future reference,
to enable the  **select element by click** tool some times you have to click on
**Refresh** button first (inside the debug panel).

No idea why but works most of the time.

Comment: This is due to the IE8 developer tools not updating the displayed HTML tree to reflect the current state of the DOM. Hitting the refresh button will update the tree based on the current DOM state. Modern browser dev tools do this update automatically without user intervention.